# Raid 1 seeding to speed up identical installs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, cloning

I was thinking of installing Ubuntu on one of our Dell servers in a RAID 1 configuration, then using the mirrored drive as the primary drive in a second  identical server with another RAID 1 setup. Essentially installing the OS once and using the redundant drive as a seed for subsequent setups.

Has anyone tried this? Success or failures?

Comment: Software or hardware raid?

Comment: Hardware. Both using identical controllers and firmware. Bought four servers and would like to use one drive to "rebuild" the array on the others.

Comment: Done it on HP hardware.  Should work for Dell, but wouldn't be able to swear to it.